# Can you use an asterisk (*) to filter a column in a WHERE clause under SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

For example

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director=*
```

Comment: What would be the point of this?

Comment: The point is that my application will have several optional filters. If I dynamically create the query in my ASP.NET C# class, it will be a bunch of unnecessary coding. 

Instead, I can leave the filters in the query and only change the value. That avoids a lot of mess. THANKS ALL!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you would need to use the LIKE operator and the % wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director like '%';
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to buy myself a T-SQL book!

Answer (score 7):

You can use LIKE;

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director LIKE '%' --all
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director LIKE 'john landis' --exact
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director LIKE 'steve%berg' --with wildcard
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director LIKE '%' --all :NO! This is the same as SELECT * FROM MOVIES WHERE DIRECTOR IS NOT NULL. The query will omit all rows where Director is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE director like '%'
```

this is the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIKE` and wildcards for that:

```
select * from movies where director like '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for results with ANY director, you can just leave the `WHERE director=` part off entirely.

If you're looking to do a partial match, you could do `WHERE director like '%Lucas%'`, which would return the equivalent of `*LUCAS*`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I'm trying to solve is not using a bunch of IF statements to build a query. With the LIKE % operator, I can have one query string and replace the placeholder values with whatever filter value is present. If a filter value is not presented by the user, I only need to replace it with %.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a director represented by `*` you would have to enclose it in between single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE director='*'
```

If you're looking for any director just leave the `where` on out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from movies where director like '%'
```

This will NOT return every row: rows where director is null will be omitted (at least with MSSQL).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I'm glad all of the attributes in the database are non-null then...